# To scale values from Matlab's spectrogram to real range

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

I run

```
spectrogram(data, 64, 60, 256, 2,  'yaxis');
```

I get

[image]

I want to get range from 0 to 180 Hz, instead of normalised range from 0 to 1.
I can change axis by

```
axis([0 450 0 180])
```

but it does not change the values.

I run unsuccessfully

```
spectrogram(180 .* data, 64, 60, 256, 2,  'yaxis');
```

**How can you scale the range from normalised to real range?**

Comment: [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) actually has the time as y-axis and the frequency as x-axis. So are you sure you haven't just labeled your axes wrong?

Comment: @thewaywewalk You are right. I am plotting the fourier transform of the data, instead of time and frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-axis should be frequency. You need to know the sampling rate `fs` (is it 2 ?) of `data`. Then the frequency range will be `(0:63)/64*fs`

Actually you can get the frequency output in the spectrogram function:

```
[B,F,T]=spectrogram(data,64,60,256,2);  % if fs = 2 in your case
```

`F` is the frequency range.

Comment: How can you plot time-frequency plot from those points in F and T? I get 129x1 double for F and 1x218 double for T.

Comment: use imagesc(abs(B)), and the F is for the column, while T for the row

Comment: **imagesc(T, F, abs(B))** seems to be working. Still the problem with range. Values are from [0,1], although should be [0,180] Hz.

Comment: F*fs is your actual frequency, (2*F) in your case. see my answer on (0:63)/64*fs. They are equivalent. But the problem is, your sampling rate is only 2 Hz, so you won't get 180 Hz signal.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! I changed **fs = 360** so I get **180 Hz** max, which I know should be the maximal frequency.

Comment: I need to now rotate the picture to get peaks from up to down. I see now this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-23%20at%2018.52.35.png Do you have any idea? Multiplying by **-1** put also minus -mark on the y-axis which I do not want.

Comment: what do you mean by that because the peaks are already on the top? You can rotate the matrix by imagesc(abs(B')), I'm not sure whether that is what you want.

Comment: It puts those peaks to the left-hand-side: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-23%20at%2020.21.45.png I want those peaks down.

Comment: imagesc(abs(B(end:-1:1,:)))

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and answers in this issue!

Comment: I am thinking now an extension of the problem but for Wigner-Ville distribution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750660/to-scale-values-from-wigner-ville-distribution-to-real-range-in-matlab I have apparently a problem in initialising windows.