# To apply window function on Wigner-Ville Distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, time-frequency

We were thinking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763707/to-create-hamming-window-of-length-64-with-overlap-60-in-matlab) how to create Hamming-64 window of overlap 64.
It is done by

```
h = hamming(64);
h2 = hamming(38);
h = conv(h, h2);
```

Now, we are thinking how you can apply this window function to the resulted variabels of the Wigner-Ville Distribution function of Auger et al in [Time-Frequency Toolbox](http://tftb.nongnu.org/).
The function [tfrwv.m](http://frankyblabla.free.fr/projet/Matlab/Test/tfrwv.m) does not have any parameter for window function.

So we have these variables

```
[B,T,F] = tfrwv(data, 1:length(data), length(data));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694297/matlab-fft-xaxis-limits-messing-up-and-fftshift/9699983#9699983) is one answer to related problem, but not completely the same.
One says that apply the window function to the results

> Just multiply, point-by-point

The dimensions of **h** are 101x1 double, while **T** and **F** 5001x1 double.
So extrapolation seems to be needed to the window vector if multiplying point-by-point.

One more explanation [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/how-do-i-apply-a-function-window-to-a-signal)

> About half way through the second code block, I apply a window
>   function to a buffered signal. This is effectively a vector
>   multiplication of the window function with each buffered block of time
>   series data. I just use a sneaky diagonal matrix trick to do it
>   efficiently.

**How can you apply a window function to the variables *B, T,* and *F*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one mistake and its symptoms in my 3rd extension to lennon310's answer.
4th extension to lennon310's answer

I run

```
h = hamming(64);
h2 = hamming(38);
h = conv(h, h2);    
B = 0; T = 0; F = 0;    
data1 = filter(data(1 : 64),1,h); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
for i=1:133
    data1 = filter(data( 1 + i*37 : 64 + i*37 ),1,h); [b,t,f] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
    B = [B b']; T = [T t]; F = [F; f];       
end
data1 = filter(data(4959 : 5001),1,h); [b,t,f] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
B = [B b']; T = [T t]; F = [F; f];       
T = 49.8899*T;      % dummy constant to get appropriate time interval
```

and get pictures like this

[image]

I have not managed to show all thin peaks in one picture.
A new question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860895/to-make-all-peaks-clearly-visible-in-matlab).

I am plotting this by

```
t = 1/360; % 360 samples per second
fs = 360.5;
imagesc(T*t, F*fs, abs(B))
```

The algorithm is accumulating the points to the right dimension.
**I am not sure if multiplying by the dummy constant is the right way to go earlier.**

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this paper](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a261839.pdf) on Wigner distribution. From page 8 to 11. I think `tfr(indices,icol) = x(ti+tau,1) .* conj(x(ti-tau,xcol));` in the code realize the formula (23). The sum and exponential part is equivalent to `tfr= fft(tfr);`. Or you also can regard those two lines of code I cited as formula (24). Note: in both the paper and code they assume the signal is periodic with `N/2`, where `N` is `length(data)`. It's Ok that you don't need to change your `data` here. They just sort kinds of extending the original data.

Cited from the paper, ***Before processing the WDF, a modified Hamming window is applied to
the time domain signal to reduce the leakage caused by the discontinuity of
the finite record of data, which will be called as data tapering.*** To my understanding, what you can do here is

```
data1 = conv(h,data);
[B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));
```

My answer is done based on your implementation. You can have a try now.

---

What I don't fully understand is the method that you created Hamming-64 window of overlap 60%. In `spectrogram`, the code split your `data` into small segments with the length of each 64. If you want to achieve the same effect of `spectrogram` with `tfrwv`, I guess you may also need to split your `data`, and use `conv(data(1:64),hamming(64))`, `conv(data(38:101),hamming(64))`,`conv(data(76:139),hamming(64))`,....as the input of `tfrwv` respectively.

Comment: Please, see my extension to your answer. We now know that my original attempt for hamming-64 is not proper. Let's try your solution. I get the error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-26%20at%2001.14.10.png when I try to use the inputs for tfrwv.

Comment: The input is data = conv(data(1:64),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data, 1:length(data), length(data)); then you re-run the program with the input data = conv(data(38:101),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data, 1:length(data), length(data));....so on and so forth. You can just try a few segments to observe if the beats are reasonable, then write a loop to operate on all the segments

Comment: there was a typo in my last comment, it should be data1 = conv(data(1:64),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1)); still throw out errors?

Comment: I finally found the bug that was in my code below. Thank you again for your patient! I opened a new question about my current problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860895/to-make-all-peaks-clearly-visible-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Extension to lennon310's answer.

I run

```
data1 = conv(h,data);
[B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));
```

and then plot it with picture of no windowing

[image]

I know that the picture without windowing is proper, since I can see there 60 Hz horizontal line caused by the settings of the measurement system in MIT-BIH arrhythmia database.
The patient is 68 years with old myocardii infarctum so the beats per second reaching 65 is proper with this method.

The picture with the implementation of my original version of hamming-64 is not proper.
The person would not live long with such beats per minute.

Answer (score 0):

2nd Extension to lennon310's answer

```
data1 = conv(data(1:64),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
data1 = conv(data(38:101),hamming(64)); [b,t,f] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));
```

I do not know how I should combine the picees of data from *b* to *B*.
Matrix diagonalization does not seem to be the appropriate choice.

I run using only `hamming(64)` for simplification, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781159/to-make-block-diagonal-matrix-out-of-square-matrices-faster-in-matlab) about implementation of matrix diagonalization

```
    B = 0; T = 0; F = 0;    
    data1 = conv(data(1 : 64),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
    for i=1:10
        data1 = conv(data( 1 + i*37 : 64 + i*37 ),hamming(64)); [b,t,f] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));    
        B = blkdiag(B,b); T = [T t]; F = [F; f];
    end
```

I get

[image]

This is not proper result.
The problem is in understanding what the matrix **B** should be.
**What should the matrix B look like after adding *b* to *B*?**

Comment: I think size(B(1:floor(numel(F)/2), :))) should be consistent with (numel(T),numel(F))?

Comment: also confirm the size is consistent in T and t, B and b, F and f before you implement B = [B b]; T = [T t]; F = [F f]; (1*64,or 64*1, etc)

Comment: Do you understand which points the matrix **B** contains? I think it is the data for time-frequency. So thinking if appending vertically and horizontally after each iteration is appropriate.

Comment: In your loop is size(b,1)=127? If so the row of b is time. Use B=[B b']; Besides, use filter instead of conv: filter(data(1 : 64),1,hamming(64))

Comment: @lennon310 Size of *b* is now 64 when using filter -command. It was 127 with convolution command. I added 3rd extension of your answer below.