# Two time-frequency pictures in one picture in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-frequency

I have two figures which have same spaces in domain and range:

[image]

and

[image]

I follow the manual [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/subimage.html) about `subimage`

```
image1 = imagesc(T*t, F*fs, abs(B));
subimage(T*t, image1);    
image2 = imagesc(T*t, F*fs, abs(B'));
subimage(T*t, image2);
```

but I get no picture.
Probably, I should use  the command `infuse` instead.
I still do not understand how should I should be passing different Y-values and Time-Frequency Representation to the command.

It seems that the command is not designed for three parameters.

**How can you make one picture out of two time-frequency plots in Matlab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
subimage(T*t, F*fs, uint8(abs(B)));
```

otherwise you are trying to `imagesc(T*t)`, a line

You may need to scale `abs(B)` to [0,255] if the value in B is out of `uint8` range:

```
B1=abs(B);
B1=B1/max(B1(:))*256; 
subimage(T*t, F*fs, uint8(B1));
```

Comment: The values of this **image1 = imagesc(T*t, F*fs, abs(B'));** is integer. So cannot store *imagesc* object that way. I am not sure if *imagesc* is the right way to go.

Comment: The objects *image1* and *image2* are still integers. So no proper result.

Comment: No proper result still.

Comment: that's strange cuz I used B=magic(800) for a test, it seems to work for me

Comment: Please, see this is what I am doing and getting: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-31%20at%2020.20.01.png I get the same result with your **magic(800)**. I have exactly the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860895/to-make-all-peaks-clearly-visible-in-matlab

Comment: did you clear all the variables and close all the figures before you started running B=magic(800); and all the rest code? I didn't reproduce your result, and I couldn't find out where is your 10^10 coming from at the y-axis

Comment: I have always **clear all; close all;** in all codes. I managed to see something by having **T = 5000*T** for one figure: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-01%20at%2012.18.50.png

Comment: I managed to get things forward here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860895/to-make-all-peaks-clearly-visible-in-matlab Can you provide a simple example how you meld two pictures together in Matlab, like vertical and horizontal lines, please.

Comment: So you don't need subimage any more? I will take a look at your new post now. Thanks

Comment: I do not know if I need subimage or not. I want to plot two images in the same picture. I do not remember how. It should be easy. The following plots for instance only the peaks along the y-axis **imagesc(T*t, F*fs, B); hold on; imagesc(T*t, F*fs, B');** which is not what is intended.